# Upgrade Apache in XAMPP installation

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp

How would I go about upgrading Apache inside a XAMPP/LAMPP Installation?

It has just been released that the current version of Apache being shipped with XAMPP is vulnerable to a local privilege escalation. (CVE-2019-0211)

I know it can only be used if the user already has limited rights on a computer but still, I thought this would be a good time to learn how to.

Thanks

**EDIT: They finally updated the version of Apache bundled with XAMPP (Took over a week and ignored messages)**

[More Info on Vulnerability](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2019/04/serious-apache-server-bug-gives-root-to-baddies-in-shared-host-environments/)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just doing a quick web search I'm finding several guides for upgrading just Apache in XAMPP. Have you tried any of these? Also, which OS are you running XAMPP on?

Comment: @music2myear I did google and wasn't able to find a solution, they all advise (ones i found) to reinstall XAMPP not just Apache in XAMPP, which defeats the point as the Apache being bundled with XAMPP is the one with the vulnerability.

Comment: If the only way to upgrade components of XAMPP is to wait for those components to be updated in the XAMPP build itself, then that is the only way to do it. You don't have another option, and Ludiusvox' answer below, though awkwardly phrased, is the correct answer. At least the first part it. Migrations to IIS aren't simple. You should visit the XAMPP forums to find out their plans to fix this. However, that vulnerability is about multi-tenant site security, and the fact you appear to be hosting a multi-tenant WP install on a basic Windows server using XAMPP is... concerning.

Comment: I am not, I am just security concious and when I learnt about this vulnerability I thought it a good idea to learn how to mitigate it on my own local development environment as it is only a matter of time before another vulnerability is found that compromises it in a bigger way that would effect the security in my local development environment and by extension my workstation.

Answer (score -1):

I would try reinstall XAMPP, or waiting for a new build release or emailing XAMPP and inform them of the issue and maybe they will issue a patch.  I think XAMPP is an open source project and is not going to have the tech support like a Microsoft project, but if a new build isn't released you can always use IIS instead.

Comment: The XAMPP available atm has the vulnerable version of Apache like mentioned in my question